# Convert Enumeration to a Set/List

Tags: java, collections, conventions

Is there some one-liner bridge method to dump a given *Enumeration* to `java.util.List` or `java.util.Set`?

Something built-in like `Arrays.asList()` or `Collection.toArray()` should exist somewhere, but I'm unable to find that in my IntelliJ debugger's evaluator window (and Google/SO results, too).

Answer (score 409, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.list()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list%28java.util.Enumeration%29) to convert an `Enumeration` to a `List` in one line:

```
List<T> list = Collections.list(enumeration);
```

There's no similar method to get a `Set`, however you can still do it one line:

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>(Collections.list(enumeration));
```

Comment: Somehow I missed this method while lurking in the autocompletion dropdown. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

How about this: [Collections.list(Enumeration e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list-java.util.Enumeration-) returns an `ArrayList<T>`

Answer (score 11):

If you need `Set` rather than `List`, you can use [EnumSet.allOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)).

```
Set<EnumerationClass> set = EnumSet.allOf(EnumerationClass.class);
```

**Update**: JakeRobb is right. My answer is about java.lang.Enum instead of java.util.Enumeration. Sorry for unrelated answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the asker was asking about java.util.Enumeration, the legacy cousin of Iterator, not java.lang.Enum, the thing you get when you use the 'enum' keyword.

Comment: I did a google search for "java convert enum into a set" and this thread came back as the first response.   @Timur gets my upvote.

Answer (score 5):

When using guava (See [doc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#forEnumeration-java.util.Enumeration-)) there is `Iterators.forEnumeration`. Given an `Enumeration x` you can do the following:

to get a immutable Set:

```
ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterators.forEnumeration(x));
```

to get a immutable List:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterators.forEnumeration(x));
```

to get a hashSet:

```
Sets.newHashSet(Iterators.forEnumeration(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also in Apache commons-collections
`EnumerationUtils.toList(enumeration)`

Answer (score -2):

I needed same thing and this solution work fine, hope it can help someone also

```
Enumeration[] array = Enumeration.values();
List<Enumeration> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

then you can get the .name() of your enumeration.

Comment: Your answer shows how to convert an array into a list and it only happens that you have an array of Enumerations. The question was about Enumeration->List conversion.